# Insert checkbox data to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

My problem is as follows.
[This is my mySQL table, and HTML form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4qp5.jpg). I need to findout a PHP code to insert the checkbox data to mySQL table.

If a checkbox is checked I want to fill that particular column as "1" else fill it as "0".

A single row is added in one time.

I am using 2 PHP files.

**1) regForm.php**

```
<html>

<form method="get" action="regCode.php">

ID: <input type="text" name="id"/></br>

Select Available dates: </br>
Monday <input type="checkbox" value="monday"></br>
Tuesday <input type="checkbox" value="tuesday"></br>
Wednesday <input type="checkbox" value="wednesday"></br>
Thursday <input type="checkbox" value="thursday"></br>
Friday <input type="checkbox" value="friday"></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br></br>

</html>
```

**2) regCode.php**

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#FFFCC">
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='username';
$dbpass='password';
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if(!$conn)
{
    die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
}


$sql="INSERT INTO available_days (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday) VALUES
()";



mysql_select_db('testdb');
$retval=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if(!$retval)
{
    die('could not add data'.mysql_error());
}

$message="Successfully Added ID No: ".mysql_insert_id();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); window.location.href='regForm.php';</script>";

mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without any attempt at coding it this question is too broad. SO is not a code writing service, so you need to show some attempt at solving the problem and then ask when you have a specific issue with it.

Comment: Just use `isset()`. It returns a boolean, but if cast to an integer it will give your 1 or 0. `$monday = (int)isset($_POST['monday'])` - now you just need to insert it ;-)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I edited and put my code there.

Comment: @Qirel, I've edited my question and added my code. Can you tell me something to do with that code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Look on answer section

Answer (score 2):

```
    # Please Try again below code. #  

      <?php 
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost:8080') {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db = 'test';
    }

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($db, $conn) or die('Could not select database.');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $monday = isset($_POST['day_name']['monday']) ? $_POST['day_name']['monday'] : 0;
        $tuesday = isset($_POST['day_name']['tuesday']) ? $_POST['day_name']['tuesday'] : 0;
        $wednesday = isset($_POST['day_name']['wednesday']) ? $_POST['day_name']['wednesday'] : 0;
        $thursday = isset($_POST['day_name']['thursday']) ? $_POST['day_name']['thursday'] : 0;
        $friday = isset($_POST['day_name']['friday']) ? $_POST['day_name']['friday'] : 0;

        //echo "INSERT INTO `available_day` (`monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`) VALUES ('".$monday."', '".$tuesday."', '".$wednesday."', '".$thursday."', '".$friday."')"; 

        $sql_add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `available_day` (`monday`, `tuesday`, `wednesday`, `thursday`, `friday`) VALUES ('".$monday."', '".$tuesday."', '".$wednesday."', '".$thursday."', '".$friday."')");

        if(!$sql_add)
        {
            die('could not add data'.mysql_error());
        }

        $message="Successfully Added ID No: ".mysql_insert_id();
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');   window.location.href='index6.php';</script>";

    }

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="contact_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class="form-group" >
       <input type="checkbox" name="day_name[monday]" value="1">Mon<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="day_name[tuesday]" value="1"> Tues<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="day_name[wednesday]" value="1"> Wed<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="day_name[thursday]" value="1"> Thu<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="day_name[friday]" value="1"> Fri<br>

    <input name="submit" type ="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="border-radius: 0px; background-color: midnightblue; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888; color: white;">
  </div> 

</form>
```

Comment: `method="get"` in the form, but `$_POST` in PHP, doesn't quite work that way. Besides, that indexing doesn't match the names of the HTML form provided.

Answer (score 1):

**1) regForm.php**

```
<form method="post" action="regCode.php">
ID: <input type="text" name="id"/></br>

Select Available dates: </br>
Monday <input type="checkbox" value="1" name='monday'></br>
Tuesday <input type="checkbox" value="1" name='tuesday'></br>
Wednesday <input type="checkbox" value="1" name='wednesday'></br>
Thursday <input type="checkbox" value="1" name='thursday'></br>
Friday <input type="checkbox" value="1" name='friday'></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br></br>
</html>
```

**2) regCode.php**

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#FFFCC">
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='username';
$dbpass='password';
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if(!$conn)
{
    die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $monday = isset($_POST['monday']) ?  $_POST['monday'] : 0;
   $tuesday = isset($_POST['tuesday']) ? $_POST['tuesday'] : 0;
   $wednesday = isset($_POST['wednesday']) ? $_POST['wednesday'] : 0;
   $thursday = isset($_POST['thursday']) ? $_POST['thursday'] : 0;
   $friday = isset($_POST['friday']) ? $_POST['friday'] : 0;

   $sql="INSERT INTO available_days (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday) VALUES ('".$monday."', '".$tuesday."', '".$wednesday."', '".$thursday."', '".$friday."')";

  mysql_select_db('testdb');
  $retval=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

  if(!$retval)
  {
    die('could not add data'.mysql_error());
  }
  $message="Successfully Added ID No: ".mysql_insert_id();
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('$message') window.location.href='regForm.php';</script>";
  mysql_close($conn);
  }
  ?>
</body>
```

If the db columns are INT please replace the with following code

```
 $monday = isset($_POST['monday']) ?  1 : 0;
 $tuesday = isset($_POST['tuesday']) ? 1 : 0;
 $wednesday = isset($_POST['wednesday']) ? 1 : 0;
 $thursday = isset($_POST['thursday']) ? 1 : 0;
 $friday = isset($_POST['friday']) ? 1 : 0;
```

And query like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO available_days (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday) VALUES ($monday, $tuesday, $wednesday, $thursday, $friday)";
```

Comment: It adds all "0" to the database whether I check the check boxes or not. Can you help me fixing it please?

Comment: `method="get"` in your form, but `$_POST['monday']` in PHP - that's why.

Comment: @NSJ the method was 'get' thats why its added all 0, please change method = 'post'

Comment: Hi @Qirel, still it adds "0" for all columns despite checking or not the check boxes. :(

Comment: @NSJ if the db columns are INT change code accordingly in the answer.