# How do I store a checkbox value as yes in MySql Database - PHP

Tags: php, sql

So when a user creates an account and they have to tick the checkbox to proceed which works, but how do I store that they accepted it (even though they cannot make an account without accpecting it). But we want to store it nonetheless.

Checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="accepted">
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST['agree'] != 'accepted') {
             $error[] = 'Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy';
    } else {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT termsAccepted FROM members WHERE termsAccepted = :??????');
    $stmt->execute(array(':??????' => $?????));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert checkbox data to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778078/insert-checkbox-data-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checkbox isn't checked, there wont be any `agree` index in the `$_POST` variable so check its existence beforehand to prevent throwing warnings in the log.

After that you can use an UPDATE query to modify the column **termsAccepted** in your **members** table.

pseudo code:

```
if (isset($_POST['agree']) && $_POST['agree'] == 'accepted') {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE members SET termsAccepted=1 WHERE id = :user_id');
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id));
}
```

Tip: If you're only storing `true` or `false`, you can use the datatype TINYINT(1) or BOOLEAN for the column **termsAccepted** as it stores only two states.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a if query in your "else" query

```
if ($_POST['agree'] == 'accepted') {
 $checkbox = "true";
} else {
 $checkbox = "false";
}
```

And than you can add $checkbox to your executing array, but you should revise the prepared statement.